# DAO is null despite @EJB annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb, dao

This is my first Java EE app with JPA Hibernate DAO & EJB. I'm stuck on a problem where despite injecting my Dao is null. I searched a lot about this problem but everything not worked. Maybe someone help me.

This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>enities.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/enities"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value=  "true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="jpa-test2" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source> jdbc/JPABDD</jta-data-source>
        <class>enities.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOne.JtaPlatform"/>
<!--            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "select u from User u")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String surname;

    @Column(nullable = false,length = 100)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 10)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserType userType;

    //getters and setter 
}
```

WebServlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "TesterWeb", urlPatterns = "/TesterWeb")
public class TesterWeb extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private IUserDAOLocal uL;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
        try{
            out.println("<html><head><title>Servlet SearchUser</title></head>");
            out.println("<body><h1>Dodaj użytkownika</h1>");

            User u = new User();
            u.setName("Paulina");
            u.setSurname("Muminek");
            u.setEmail("muminek.wlesie@onet.pl");
            u.setPassword("muminek78");
            u.setUserType(UserType.client);

            uL.create(u);
            out.println("<h1>Dodany użytkownik: ");
            System.out.println(u.getName() + u.getSurname());
            out.println(u.getName() + " " + u.getSurname());
            out.println("</h1></u1></body></html>");

        } finally{
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

IUserDaoLocal

```
@Local
public interface IUserDAOLocal extends IUserDAO{
}
```

IUserDao

```
@Remote
public interface IUserDAO extends IGenericDao<User>{
}
```

GenericFacade with EntityManager

```
@Stateless
public class GenericFacade<T> implements IGenericDao<T> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "jpa-test2")
    protected EntityManager em;
    private final Class<T> entityClass;

    public GenericFacade() {
        Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
        entityClass = (Class<T>) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void create(T entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
    }

   //other methods like update, remove...

}
```

IGenericDao interface

```
public interface IGenericDao<T> {
    void create(T entity);
    void edit(T entity);
    void remove(T entity);
    T find(Object id);
    List <T> findAll();
    Long count();
}
```

When I want add User in TesterWeb class I got an exception:

```
[2023-06-12T13:00:37.031360+02:00] [GF 7.0.5] [WARNING] [] [jakarta.enterprise.web.vs.server] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[TesterWeb]: Servlet.service() for servlet TesterWeb threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "DAO.IUserDAOLocal.create(Object)" because "this.uL" is null
    at TesterWeb.doGet(TesterWeb.java:33)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:527)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:503)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:188)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:425)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
]]
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myShop</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myShop</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.9.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/ejb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I want to add: It isn't SPRING framework

Comment: What server are you running on, are you sure it supports EJBs? Be aware that Tomcat doesnt support EJBs. I'd suggest OpenLiberty which is fully Jakarta EE (https://openliberty.io)

Comment: It is a Glassfish 7.0.5

Comment: Just create plain stateless ejb without all this "generics" stuff. Also dont create remote interface, nobody uses remote ejb access any more.